# How do I access another data in firebase database in the cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase real-time database and trying to create a trigger when a field called `ignore` gets added to my DB. But I first want to access another data in the db and use if in my function. My functions looks as follows:

```
exports.dbTest2 = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/ignore')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const uid = context.params.uid
    console.log(`Current User ${uid}`)

    // Data added at the location
    const ignoreData = snapshot.val()
    const endTime = new Date(ignoreData.endTime).toString()

    const scheduleRef = snapshot.ref.parent.child('schedule')
    console.log(scheduleRef)

    let scheduleArr = [ /*something*/ ]
    return snapshot.ref.parent.child('schedule').set(scheduleArr)

  });
```

and my DB looks like this:

[image]

From my current reference path `{uid}/ignore` I want to get the first element in the `schedule` reference (circled in the image). In my code above, I tried to console log the reference, but it seems like there is no such way to get the value from that object.

How can I get the object circled in the image in my cloud function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting `functions.database.ref` like this:

```
exports.dbTest2 = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/ignore')
    .onCreate((snapshotIgnore, context) => {

      const uid = context.params.uid;

      admin.database().ref(`/${uid}/schedule`).once('value', snapshotSchedule => {
        console.log(snapshotSchedule.val()[0]);
      });
    });
```

Comment: `console.log(snapshot.val().schedule[0])` gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: what's your `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: it prints out the data inside `ignore`. So, `{ dsf: 'fds' }` in my case

Comment: please take a look at updated answer

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: functions.database.ref(...).on is not a function`

Comment: sorry, it should be `once` not `on`

Comment: Getting the same error: `TypeError: functions.database.ref(...).once is not a function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192163/discussion-between-hilarion-galushka-and-dawn17).